# Spreading object across a div with one of them centred using flex

Tags: html, css, flexbox

I'm making a navbar in which I have a logo and 2 buttons that are used as links. When the text in the buttons has the same length, using `justify-content: center;` on all of the three elements does what I want, meaning it puts the logo in the center and the other two on one side each (I apply some margins to the logo to space them out, even margins on both sides). It becomes a problem when the text in the buttons isn't the same length. Not only do the margins not space the elements in the right way, the logo is not centered anymore (even if I remove the margins, the logo isn't centered anymore). To give you a Bootstrap example, I would like the objects to use something similar to `justify-content-around` in bootstrap. What should I do?

```
<div class="header">
<button class="activePage"><a href="map.html">Home</a></button>
<img src="logo.png" height="100px">
<button><a href="colorgame.html" target="_blank">Color Game</a></button>
</div>

.header{
        display: flex;
        justify-content: center;
        height: 50px;
        margin-bottom: 50px;
        background: blue;
    }

    .header img{
        margin-left: 10%;
        margin-right: 10%;
    }
```

This is how it looks. Looking at the bottom logo, you can clearly see the navbar logo isn't centered.
[How it looks](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Epykb.png)

EDIT: Managed to fix it by looking into how it works in Bootstrap. It's fairly simple, you just apply some properties to the

```
ul{
        list-style-type: none;
        display: flex;
        -ms-flex-pack: distribute !important;
        justify-content: space-around !important;
```

}

Comment: Could you share some code or better a [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/) with us please.

Comment: No, better with actually code *in question* than a Fiddle -- a Fiddle may expire, it's a third party resource, and when it expires it will make the question useless. Always paste code inline, here.

Comment: Your problem is widths of your buttons that aren't the same value, which makes the visual impression that logo isn't in the middle. Mathematically, it is, but since buttons are of different width (which again, depends on the span of text in each button) it appears that it isn't. It's a common problem to solve. But I would wait for your code snippet before attempting answering this.

Comment: I added the code

Answer (score 0):

Without a code example, this is the best I could cobble together from your description. Is it helpful in your goal?

```css
ul {
  background-color: #FDD;
  padding: 10px;
  width: 80%;
  margin: auto;
  list-style-type: none;
  
  
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
}

ul li {
  background-color: #DFD;
  
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  width: 33%;
  text-align: center;
  vertical-align: middle;
}
```

```html
<nav>
  <ul>
    <li><a href="#">Link</a></li>
    <li><a href="#"><img src="logo.jpg" width="100" height="100"></a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Link</a></li>
  </ul>
</nav>

<nav>
  <ul>
    <li><a href="#">Long Link</a></li>
    <li><a href="#"><img src="logo.jpg" width="100" height="100"></a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Link</a></li>
  </ul>
</nav>
```

Comment: doesn't work, the logo is still not in the middle... is there any better way to do this than flex?

Answer (score 0):

You probably have something like:

```
<div>
    <img src="https://cdn.hasselblad.com/dd31675c3502ea1d45f69a100d96e4b4ead306a7_b9403385_thumb.jpg">
    <nav>
        <a>Lorem ipsum</a>
        <a>dolor</a>
        <a>sit amet</a>
    </nav>
</div>
```

A logo image followed by an amount of anchors (or buttons, does not matter). And the problem is that even though you can make the logo and the navigation element align horizontally on a common center axis, the annoying fact that the anchors do not have identical width because of their textual content, makes the visual impression that the logo and the anchors aren't really centered.

Let's just assume the following CSS just to illustrate what it normally would look like:

```
a {
    outline: 1px dotted red; /* Just so that we can see the span of each box. */
    text-align: center; /* We want every anchor's text centered within its box. */
}
img {
    /* Make the logo image a block element so we can have it centered using equal margins on either side. */
    display: block;
    margin: auto;
}
```

You can center the navigation bar itself using CSS Flex box model for the `div` element, or using `width: fit-content` and `margin: auto` on the navigation bar, this isn't really important for the solution:

```
div {
    align-items: center;
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
}

/* OR */

nav {
    margin: auto;
    width: fit-content; /* Or `-moz-fit-content` if the former isn't supported */
}
```

We then have:

[image: Without the navigation bar as Grid-level element]

You can see that the horizontal space to the left and right of the image is the same, yet because of varying width of the anchors, things appear a bit "off".

#### A solution using the CSS Grid box model

One of the more elegant ways I know to fix this is to use the Grid box model in CSS, making your `nav` element a grid box:

```
nav {
    display: grid;
    grid-auto-columns: 1fr; /* Every column occupies fairly distributed (between siblings) amount of free space. */
    grid-auto-flow: column;
}
```

Which gives us:

[image: With navigation bar as Grid-level element]

Obviously, you can even make and probably would prefer the navigation bar the same width as the image, several ways to do that, I would probably set the `width` of the `div` element to `fit-content`. Not every user agent supports that, Firefox, for example supports `-moz-fit-content`, a prefixed version of the value.

Comment: I actually have the logo as the middle element (instead of dolor in your example). Haven't used grid since I haven't learned it yet, that is why I try it with flex.